# find element has the class or not in scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am new in scrapy.

I get list of li tag from xpath selector : `categories = categories_container.xpath('li')`
now I have find out which category element has the css class of "particular class which not in other li".

what I can do to find that li ?

thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use `//li[contains(@class, "particular class")]`

Answer (score 0):

categories_container.xpath('//li[contains(@class, "particular class")]').getall()

or css

categories_container.css('li.classname').getall()